# Plot bar chart in multiple subplot rows

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

I have a simple long-form dataset I would like to generate bar charts from. The dataframe looks like this:

```
data = {'Year':[2019,2019,2019,2020,2020,2020,2021,2021,2021],
        'Month_diff':[0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2],
        'data': [12,10,13,16,12,18,19,45,34]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I would like to plot a bar chart that has 3 rows, each for 2019, 2020 and 2021. X axis being `month_diff` and `data` goes on Y axis.
How do I do this?

If the data was in different columns, then I could have just used this code:

```
df.plot(x="X", y=["A", "B", "C"], kind="bar")
```

But my `data` is in a single column and ideally, I'd like to have different row for each year.

Comment: This is a very typical use case for Seaborn: `sns.catplot(kind='bar', data=df, x='Month_diff', y='data', row='Year', height=2, aspect=4)`. [docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html)  [resulting plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKzYi.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 1. [`seaborn.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html)

The simplest option for a long-form dataframe is the [`seaborn.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) wrapper, as Johan said:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.catplot(data=df, x='Month_diff', y='data', row='Year',
            kind='bar', height=2, aspect=4)
```

[image]

---

#### 2. [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) + [`DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

Without seaborn:

- [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) from long-form to wide-form (1 year per column)
- use [`DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) with `subplots=True` to put each year into its own subplot (and optionally `sharey=True`)

```
(df.pivot(index='Month_diff', columns='Year', values='data')
   .plot.bar(subplots=True, sharey=True, legend=False))
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Note that if you prefer a single grouped bar chart (which you alluded to at the end), you can just leave out the `subplots` param:

```
df.pivot(index='Month_diff', columns='Year', values='data').plot.bar()
```

[image]

---

#### 3. [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html)

You can also iterate the `df.groupby('Year')` object:

- Create a [`subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) grid of axes based on the number of groups (years)
- Plot each group (year) onto its own subplot row

```
groups = df.groupby('Year')
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=len(groups), ncols=1, sharex=True, sharey=True)

for (name, group), ax in zip(groups, axs):
    group.plot.bar(x='Month_diff', y='data', legend=False, ax=ax)
    ax.set_title(name)

fig.supylabel('data')
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]